# Overlaying OpenStreetMap of island on bathymetry

Tags: qgis

I want to make a map where I have the OpnvKarte of Diego Garcia island overlying a bathymetry layer.  However, the Opnvkarte layer covers the bathymetry layer.  Is there a way to trim the island or mask the coastline of the island, so that it overlays the bathymetry?

I was able to get run a query in QuickOSM to get the coastline data, but I would like the OSM or OPNVkarte polygon of the island, as well.  Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDtOX.png)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the Raster>Extraction>Clip raster by Mask layer?

Comment: Hmm - I gave that a try, but it doesn't seem to be working.  I guess I'm after a way to purely extract the Island from the OPNvkarte (or from OpenStreetMap) as a Polygon so that it can overlay the bathymetry.